# Python: display order of in input arguments with argparse

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

In Python, using `argparse`, is there a way to directly specify in which order the arguments will be displayed on screen, when calling the script with `-h`?

More specifically, I would like to display a number of arguments *after* some others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the order is the order in which you `add_argument` (for each group) since internally they're stored in a list.

e.g.:

```
import argparse

args = ('foo','bar','baz','qux')

#This is not the order the get printed in, so it's not using a dict...
print (set(args))  

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
for x in args:
    parser.add_argument('--{0}'.format(x),help=x)

parser.parse_args(['-h'])
```

results in:

```
set(['baz', 'foo', 'bar', 'qux'])
usage: test.py [-h] [--foo FOO] [--bar BAR] [--baz BAZ] [--qux QUX]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO   foo
  --bar BAR   bar
  --baz BAZ   baz
  --qux QUX   qux
```

Of course, different python implementations are welcome to re-implement `argparse` as they see fit, but since it's pure python, I don't see any reason for them to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: True. I quickly assumed arguments were alphabetically sorted, but as you said they are actually displayed in the order they appear on the code.